# jQuery Cookie returns [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

I've got these two functions:-

```
function BlogsButtons() {
    $.removeCookie('BlogURLs', { expires: 7, path: '/en/blogs/' });

    var urls = "";
    $("#list-of-blogs div.news-article").each(function() {
       urls += $(this).find('a:first-child').attr('href');
       if(!$(this).is(":last-child")) {
           urls += ",";
       }
    });

    $.cookie('BlogURLs', urls, { expires: 7, path: '/en/blogs/' });
    var a = 1;
}
```

and

```
function BlogsNextLastButtons() {
    var blogsURLs = $.cookie('BlogURLs', { expires: 7, path: '/en/blogs/' });
    // .. to do rest of function here
}
```

I have a page which lists blogs, and I want to get the list of URL's and comma separate them and store them in a cookie. Then on the page that has the actual article on, I want to retrieve this list from the cookie, split it by comma and use basic array surfing to find the item in the list before the current page URL and then item after. The logic for this works.

In the second function on that first line, when I try to get back the value of $.cookie('BlogURLs'), the console shows me [object Object]. I've read on another post that this can be caused by a cookie being overwritten, but this is definitely the only place on the site where a cookie with such a name is used.

Also, interesting to note is that the line of code `var a = 1`, I can see the cookie value here in the correct format. So whatever causes this happens after the page with the actual article on loads up.

Stuff I've tried:-

- Renaming the cookie name to something absurd that can't possibly be used.
- Changing the path of the cookie
- Instead of doing removeCookie, I tried setting the cookie to null, empty string and an expiry time of -1.

Nothing seems to work. In an exact duplicate of this function above, we have no issues, the cookie name there is different again, as is the path.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Check that the path you're accessing from is correct for that cookie. It seems to work absolutely fine when your remove the `path` restriction: https://jsfiddle.net/cn8nnz5w/

Comment: How do you mean sorry? That the path exists on the site?

Comment: That's right. The path is a restriction on the cookie. It means that the cookie can only be read when accessed from that path of the website URL.

Comment: Ok. If I have i set to /en/blogs/ and then I try and read it on /en/blogs/my-details-link/ will that work?

Comment: Yes, that should work.